# i am trying to copy a string in c using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
char ch0[10] = "hello";
char ch1[10];

void main(){
    clrscr();
    char *pt0 = ch0;
    char *pt1 = ch1;
    puts(pt0);

    while(*pt0 != '\0')
    {
        *pt1++ = *pt0++;
    }
    *pt1 = '\0';

    printf("value of ch1 =");
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(ch1); i++){
        printf("%c",ch1[i]); // prints value correctly
    }

    putchar('\n');
    printf("pointer pt1 value = %c",*pt1); // gives garbage value
    getch();
}
```

Pointer `pt1` value is not accessible however the `ch1` is pointing to the correct value.

How to access pt1?

I am not good in pointers can any only explain me the working scenario

```
output:
hello
value of ch1 =hello
pointer pt1 value= \\garbage value
```

Comment: Please spend some time on indenting / separating your code properly. It will make answering your questions easier.

Comment: After copying, `pt1` points to `ch1[5]` which has the value `\0`.

Comment: OT: `main()` returns `int` not `void`.

Comment: add pt1 = ch ; after *pt1 = '\0'; replace for-loop with printf("%s", ch1 );

Comment: what do you mean "garbage value"? i ran your code(after minor modifications) on gcc c99 and it basically didn't print anything(well, printed the '/0' char AKA ascci 0)

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like you just need to reset `pt1`.  After your copy loop, it's pointing to the end of the string in the `ch1` array.

So, after the line:

```
*pt1='\0';
```

`pt1` is pointing to the end of the string in `ch1`.  So, to print it out, you need to reset it back to `ch1`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code:

```
char *pt0 =ch;
```

should perhaps be:

```
char *pt0 =ch0;
```

Your compiler should notice that but maybe it would be better to correct it here also for consistency. Apart from this the bruceg's answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are incrementing the pointer **ptr1** and then atlast your assigning value **"NULL"**. So no longer the **ptr1** holds the **ch1**  string.

For better understanding, you can print the addresses of both **ch1** and **ptr1**. You will understand much better